# Make a link to the tabbed menu

Tags: php, html, css, url, tabs

I'm trying to make links to the tabbed menu. 
I have 4 categories on the homepage (car, van, truck and special). Each of these categories are links to the portfolio page.

My portfolio page consists of a simple filtered tabbed menu. Something like this:

```
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
        <li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".car">Car</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".van">Van</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".truck">Truck</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".special">Special</span></li>
</ul>
```

But when I click on one of those categories on the homepage, my website redirects me to the portfolio page and always show me "filter active" class (in my case it is "car" class).

And I want to make these redirects like this:

- When I click on the "Car" category on the homepage, I should be
  redirected to the "Car" class on the portfolio page.
- When I click on the "Van" category on the homepage, I should be
  redirected to the "Van" class on the portfolio page.

The same I want to make with 2 other categories.

Is there any way to make this?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve one-page-layout web? Do you want to scroll (or jump to the category, or load completely different URL?

Comment: There are 2 different pages. Homepage and portfolio page. And I want to achieve a certain class on portfolio page from homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make your `portfolio` page in this way you could use in `homepage`:

```
<a href="portfolio.html#car">Scroll to car</a>
<a href="portfolio.html#van">Scroll to van</a>
```

to redirect to `portofilo` page with hash, and based on hash the script included here decide on which element should scroll and which element of the menu should get class `active`.

Using jQuery for prove of concepct.

---

```js
$(function() {
  var filters = $('#filters');
  var hash = location.hash ? location.has : 'car';
  
  filters.find('[data-filter='+hash+']').addClass('active');
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".target-"+hash).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
  <li><span class="filter" data-filter="car">Car</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="filter" data-filter="van">Van</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="filter" data-filter="truck">Truck</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="filter" data-filter="special">Special</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="target-car">Car</div>
<div class="target-van">van</div>
```